# Can calculator show decimal as fraction?

Tags: software-recommendation, calculator

Some calculators can show a decimal as a fraction if applicable. eg. 1.333333 -> 1r1r3 on my calculator (hardware) representing \$1 \frac{1}{3}\$. Can the built in calculator do that? If not which (software) can?

** Whats wrong with my math?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use Wolfram Alpha as an web application in a few days with 11.10.
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-epiphany-320-with-web.html
With 11.10 you can install epiphany and have Wolfram Alpha as a web application and have it saved as an launch-able icon in Unity.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What are your constraints? Are you allowed to use online calculators? If so, just use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1024%2F1000) or one of the [shortcuts](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1024%2F1000) to it.

A search reveals [Qalculate](http://qalculate.sourceforge.net/), but it's a little... pink, for my taste. Perhaps it can be themed. Also, it requires the Qt library, so expect a lot of things to be installed for just this simple program if you don't have other Qt-dependent programs already on your computer.

Comment: No constraints, but I'd prefer just opening an app instead of a web app, which will take longer

Answer (score 0):

Giving below link to a bash script to do the above said
http://advantage-bash.blogspot.in/2012/03/convert-decimal-to-fraction.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.